# ANC Headset with good Microphone for Ubuntu

Tags: audio, headphones, headset

I am searching a high quality Active-Noise-Canceling headset with have a good microphone and support for Ubuntu 20.02.

I already tried:

Bose 700, Bose QC35 ii, Beyerdynammics Lagoon Traveler, Sony wh-1000xm3

But these devices seem to be mostly headphones, not headsets. And there seems to be an issue with the Linux Bluetooth stack. As soon as you turn on the microphone the audio quality gets unusable.

Since ANC is important for me, I think over-ear devices are better suited for my need.

I need silence to concentrate on my work. Several times a day I have a video-call and there I need to solid microphone. The one in my laptop is not suitable, since I type during the conversation and I don't want my client to hear the sound of the keyboard.

It can be a wired or a wireless/bluetooth device. Quality of microphone and noise-canceling are much more important for me.

I really don't want to switch the between headset and headphones for video-calls. I want one device for both tasks.

I am willing to pay up to 400 Euro.

Answer (score 2):

I have a wireless Jabra ANC Headset now (Jabra Evolve2 85)

This way the Linux Bluetooth gets avoided, since there is a custom USB-dongle which speaks to the headset.

But it is not perfect.

My voice sounds a bit strange, compared to much cheaper wired headsets.

I published my story here: https://github.com/guettli/headset